# Thunar cannot browse network

Tags: debian, samba, xfce, thunar

I've already figured out the answer, but decided to post this as a Q+A here because this bothered me for ages and it took a long time to find the solution.

Hoping this will be of use to others (or even myself) in future...

---

Unable to browse network with Thunar.

OS: Debian XFCE (minimal network install)

Issue: Open Thunar and click "Network" -> error appears stating that operation is not supported

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that the minimal/network Debian install comes with exactly that - minimal packages.

In particular it is missing any support for Samba.

For browsing to work in Thunar:

```
sudo apt install gvfs-backends gvfs-bin
```

You may also require some or all of these packages:

```
sudo apt install smbclient samba
```

Additional note: My samba share is hosted on a TrueNAS instance. I needed to go to:

```
Network -> Global Configuration -> Enable "NetBIOS-NS"
```

Comment: Xubuntu 22.04, Feb 2023 - `gvfs-bin` seems to be deprecated, but just installing `gvfs-backends` and `smbclient` solved my problem.